# What is the name of this octagonal shape?

Tags: single-word-requests, shapes

Let's say that this image (imagining that it has eight sides):

[image: Pyramid with octagonal base]

is placed on top of this image (an octagonal prism):

[image: Octagonal pyramid]

What will the resulting shape be called?

Comment: You place an octagonal pyramid atop an octagonal prism.  But I know of no name for the combined polyhedron.

Comment: How about an *octagonal missile*?

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, I was looking for the name of the new structure....

Comment: @DanBron: Missile evokes a different image, more leaner and circular but this is more stout and having multiple faces...like a prism

Comment: Hence ***octagonal** missile*.

Comment: A "missile" is an object forcibly propelled at a target.  So don't use it here.  Unless these things will be used for throwing.

Comment: A solid with a cone on *all* surfaces is called *stellated*. I doubt that there is a name for a solid with a cone on only one surface.

Comment: I might call it an ***octagonal obelisk***

Comment: Perhaps it can be called... Art?

Comment: Call it *pencil-shaped*. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a heptadecahedron - a 17 sided solid. One of [6,415,851,530,241 topologically distinct convex heptadecahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecahedron).

You don't need to call it an irregular heptadecahedron, as all of them are.

Sorry it's not a very exciting name.

Comment: I think "heptadecahedron" is very exciting.

Answer (score 7):

It can be called an "elongated octagonal pyramid." See [elongated pyramid on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_pyramid):  "the elongated pyramids are an infinite set of polyhedra, constructed by adjoining an n-gonal pyramid to an n-gonal prism."

Of course, you're going to have to explain what you mean if you ever use this term, so its utility is questionable, unless you are referring to such things repeatedly.