# What's the name of this two-lobed shape?

Tags: single-word-requests, shapes

I got an avocado featuring a canal in the middle. The canal is not really deep but still it splits the fruit in two distinct parts. What's the name of this shape? I think "ribbed" is an exaggerated term since it features only one canal.

And what's the name of that canal? Groove?

[image: This avocado]

Comment: I noticed there are many questions asking "What is the name of.. ?", including shapes. Example: [elongated pyramid](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324182/what-is-the-name-of-this-octagonal-shape/), so I thought it's ok to ask on this site.

Comment: I utterly fail to see why this was closed as lacking in research/general reference. How exactly is one supposed to search for the name of a thing whose name you don’t know? What commonly-available reference will give you a name for this shape without already knowing it? (As it happens, I am not convinced this particular shape has a name in English, at least not a common one. But that doesn’t make the question off-topic.)

Comment: It is bilobed https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilobed.

Comment: *Groove* is a great description. I assembled an informal [collection of words used by researchers to describe such 3-D patterns](http://john.maloney.org/Patterns/patterns.htm). *Furrow* and *valley* express similar meanings and are sometimes adopted to describe microscopic or mesoscopic features.

Comment: Searching "grooved tomato" on Google brings up a lot of ribbed tomatoes. So for the moment, "Grooved avocado" seems to be the best term for this.

Comment: You could say "bum-shaped", or "clunibular", to use a Latin term which I just invented from "clunis", the Latin word for "buttock".

Comment: Maybe here is a technical term used by botanists ... perhaps try https://biology.stackexchange.com/ ??

Comment: *Brain-shaped*?

Comment: As @NigelJ said, *bilobed* or *bilobate*.

Comment: I would say "turd-shaped".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have personal experience of such an object – a kidney stone.

I had mine removed by [lithotripsy](https://www.kidney.org/atoz/content/lithotripsy) in 1984.

---

Its technical description is **bilobed.**

> Bilobed : divided into two lobes

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilobed)

---

On the other hand, it looks suspiciously like NASA's photograph of [Phobos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_(moon)), the innermost of the two satellites of Mars.

[image: Phobos_colour_2008.jpg]

---

Comment: You’re sure it was lithotripsy? :-)

Comment: @Jim I was the eighth person in the UK to get lithotripsied at St Thomas's. It was an experimental procedure back in 1984.

Comment: *"In fact, I think this might well belong to me.

I had it removed by lithotripsy in 1984 and I would like it back."* __  [After lithotripsy the stone no longer exist](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/007113.htm). Whether there is a fee for displaying its image is a genuine matter to be decided. However *bilobed* is an accurate description @NigelJ!

Comment: You might be partially compensated by my upvote @NigelJ.

Comment: No way is that pitted sphere a bilobed object.

Answer (score 6):

Avocados are **[OVOID](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ovoidal)** in shape.

**OVOIDAL** has the same meaning,  another word for *egg-shaped*. The crack that is visible on the fruit skin is called a **ridge**, a more precise term would be a **longitudinal ridge**

[image]

> Figure 4.  A.  ‘Hass’ avocado fruit with a longitudinal ridge which C. Schroeder theorized was a result of incomplete closure of the carpel.  Such fruit are often scarred on the ridge.

[Source](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.558.3081&rep=rep1&type=pdf): Avocado Fruit Abnormalities and Defects Revisited

The "canal" or "groove" mentioned in the question, and visible in the image posted by the OP is known as a (shallow) **longitudinal crack** or **crease**,; deeper cracks that penetrate the exterior skin and expose the flesh may actually cause the fruit to split and spoil.

[Source](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2468014117302224): Citrus Fruit-Cracking: Causes and Occurrence

Comment: The scholarly source article on avocado defects (pdf) makes fascinating reading @Mari-lou A.

Answer (score -1):

It might be ***orbital*** bur I'm not entirely sure.